# Заменить символы при выводе данных в таблице vue js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, replace

У меня есть модальное окно для набора внутри него номера кредитной карты (использую директиву v-mask из библиотеки vue-the-mask). Затем, при вводе номера и клике на кнопку "Добавить", номер карты должен отобразиться в отведенной для этого таблице, но при этом, 8 цифр из номера карты по середине, должны скрыться за символом *. То есть, при вводе, номер выводится в таком формате "1234 5678 9123 4567", а в таблице номер должен выглядеть таким образом "1234 **** **** 4567". Как реализовать подобное?"

Answer (score 0):

с помощью фильтров https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html .

разбить номер карты на массив и заменить цифры в 1 и 2 элементе